# Open Keepass file in Android not work

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mime-types

I'm developing a simple file browser application for android (with mono for android), which can open different files.
All works fine but I noticed that my open-method is unable to find out the mime type for **KeePass** files (kdb and kdbx), although KeePassDroid is installed. The returned string is always null for these extenstions.

Surprisingly, the pre-installed file browser on my Galaxy S 3 can start the KeePassDroid app directly.

**Why is the mime type for kdb and kdbx null**?

Find out mime type:

```
 Intent openResourceIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView);
 String mime = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension (resource.FileExtension);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the console to fix it - Just right click on the include packages, and then use them directly in C#